# How to Remove HSQLDB Datasource in Tomee?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hsqldb, apache-tomee

Apologies if I am posting a duplicate , if so please point me to original question.

I am running a tomee instance. I am configuring my data sources in context.xml and that are being pickup fine. But tomee also creates a HSQLDB datasource by default. And for few transaction it is being picked up and gives me error.

I would like to remove/ disable it from configuration so that it doesn't gives me those false error like:

> user lacks privilege or object not found.

And I would be able to see actual issue with my application.

Comment: A simple google for "tomee hsqldb" seems to indicate that you need to look in the conf/tomee.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

As Gimby said, you should define it in tomee.xml

If you are using eclipse check that your server locations is set to 
*"use Tomcat installation (take control...)"* 
and not 
*"use workspace metadata"*

usefull links:

[how-to-define-mysql-data-source-in-tomee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771783/how-to-define-mysql-data-source-in-tomee)

[MySQL datasource in TomEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954385/javaee-eclipselink-tomee-gives-java-sql-sqlsyntaxerrorexception-user-lacks/37991784#37991784)